# Javascript - setInterval to advance slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a basic image gallery following w3 schools tutorial for a manual slideshow.  I'm trying to add some functionality by using `setInterval()` to advance the images even when the user doesn't click the button.  Nothing seems to be occurring on the interval however.  Any guidance in getting a timer to advance the slides would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div align="center">
 <div class="slideViewer">
    <img class="slides" src="images/dragonborn.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/mountain.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/nords.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/dragon.jpg" style="width:50%">

    <button class="display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

var timer = setInterval(plusDivs(1), 1000);


function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display ="none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `setInterval` a function-- by calling the function in your code, you aren't passing the function, but instead the result of a single call.  Instead, pass an anonymous function that then executes what you want to occur:

```
<div align="center">
 <div class="slideViewer">
    <img class="slides" src="images/dragonborn.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/mountain.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/nords.jpg" style="width:50%">
    <img class="slides" src="images/dragon.jpg" style="width:50%">

    <button class="display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    plusDivs(1);
}, 1000);


function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display ="none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` takes as its first parameter a function. By using the double-parenthesis you actually executed the `plusDivs` function and passed its return value (undefined) to `setInterval`

Instead, try the following:

```
setInterval(function() { plusDivs(1); }, 1000);
```

Or, alternatively, modify `plusDivs` so that it doesn't need a parameter and then just pass `plusDivs` directly like so:

```
setInterval(plusDivs, 1000):
function plusDivs(n) {
    n = n || 1; // Default value
    // ...
}
```

While we're at it, it's generally not considered a good practice to use a function before it's been declared. So you should move the `plusDivs` function above the call to `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function as argument to *setInterval*. Currently, you just pass the result of calling *plusDivs* once.

Try this:

```
var timer = setInterval(() => plusDivs(1), 1000);
```

Note the parentheses and arrow - that defines an anonymous function that is executed with every interval.

Comment: Please note that if the OP needs to support IE, [fat arrows will not be an option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without transpilation.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to pass a parameter to a function and return a function

```
var plusDivs = function(n) {
    return function() {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }
}

setInterval(plusDivs(1), 1000);
```